# For each label in one array set the first k occurrences to False in another array

Tags: python, numpy

I have two (sorted) arrays, A and B, of different lengths each containing unique labels that are repeated a number of times.
The count for each label in A is less than or equal to that in B.
All labels in A will be in B, but some labels in B do not appear in A.

I need an object the same length as B where, for each label `i` in A (which occurs `k_i` times), the first `k_i` occurrences of label `i` in B need to be set to `False`.
The remaining elements should be `True`.

The following code gives me what I need, but if A and B are large, this can take a long time:

```
import numpy as np

# The labels and their frequency
A = np.array((1,1,2,2,3,4,4,4))
B = np.array((1,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5))

A_uniq, A_count = np.unique(A, return_counts = True)
new_ind = np.ones(B.shape, dtype = bool)
for i in range(len(A_uniq)):
    new_ind[np.where(B == A_uniq[i])[0][:A_count[i]]] = False

print(new_ind)
#[False False  True  True  True False False False  True False False False
#  True  True  True  True]
```

Is there a faster or more efficient way to do this? I feel like I may be missing some obvious broadcasting or vectorized solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one with `np.searchsorted` -

```
idx = np.searchsorted(B, A_uniq)
id_ar = np.zeros(len(B),dtype=int)
id_ar[idx] = 1
id_ar[A_count+idx] -= 1
out = id_ar.cumsum()==0
```

We can optimize further to compute `A_uniq,A_count` using its sorted nature instead of using `np.unique`, like so -

```
mask_A = np.r_[True,A[:-1]!=A[1:],True]
A_uniq, A_count = A[mask_A[:-1]], np.diff(np.flatnonzero(mask_A))
```

Answer (score 1):

Example without numpy

```
A = [1,1,2,2,3,4,4,4]
B = [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5]

a_i = b_i = 0
while a_i < len(A):
  if A[a_i] == B[b_i]:
    a_i += 1
    B[b_i] = False
  else:
    B[b_i] = True
  b_i += 1
# fill the rest of B with True
B[b_i:] = [True] * (len(B) - b_i)
# [False, False, True, True, True, False, False, False, True, False, False, False, True, True, True, True]
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is inspired by the one by @Divakar, using [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import groupby
A = np.array((1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4))
B = np.array((1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5))

indices = [key + i for key, group in groupby(np.searchsorted(B, A)) for i, _ in enumerate(group)]
result = np.ones_like(B, dtype=np.bool)
result[indices] = False

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[False False  True  True  True False False False  True False False False
  True  True  True  True]
```

The idea is to use [np.searchsorted](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) to find the insertion position of each element of `A`, as equal elements will have the same insertion position you have to shift by one each of them, hence the groupby. Then create an array of `True` and set the values of the `indices` to `False`.

If you can use `pandas`, compute the `indices` like this:

```
values = np.searchsorted(B, A)
indices = pd.Series(values).groupby(values).cumcount() + values
```